# Achieving Weil upper bound

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

A smooth curve has a number N of points over a field of order q bounded by the inequality
$$N<q+1+2g\sqrt{q},$$
where $g$ is the genus of the curve. Is there some simple condition for reaching a value of N close to the upper bound?

Comment: Even in the case of $g = 1$ there does not seem to be any simple condition, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.05255

Comment: This is Weil, not Weyl. And there is a huge literature on the subject: I recommend Serre's *Rational points on curves over finite fields".

Comment: Ok, corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Searching with the right spelling, I found this https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~rehmann/ECM/cdrom/3ecm/pdfs/pant3/garcia.pdf

Comment: The behavior is very different if you are interested in fixing $g$ while $q$ grows, or fixing $q$ while $g$ rows. But I think there isn't a short answer in either case.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.01928.pdf). There is an integral upper bound due to Serre: $q+1+g[2\sqrt{q}]$.